# Qemu does not boot debian squeeze for PPC on x86_64

Tags: debian, emulation, qemu, powerpc

I've downloaded qemu for ppc and I also downloaded an debian sqeeze image for the ppc from [http://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/powerpc/](http://people.debian.org/%7Eaurel32/qemu/powerpc/).

And as per that page, when I try to run the image using

```
qemu-system-ppc -hda debian_squeeze_powerpc_desktop.qcow2
```

it gives me the following error:

> qemu: could not load PowerPC bios '/c/Program Files/Qemu/ppc_rom.bin'

I then added the -L option to point to the directory containing the bios which I had earlier downloaded from the takeda toshiya qemu powerpc webpage (a quick google search with 'takeda toshiya qemu powerpc' gives it as a first link).

That zip file when unzipped creates a folder which contains the kernel as well as the ppc BIOS.

I then cd to that folder and execute:

```
./qemu-system-ppc.exe -L . -hda ../debian_squeeze_powerpc_standard.qcow2
```

to which it starts a new windows ( a shell basically ) in which I see that there are quite a few errors like as shown in this PNG image (since I cannot grab just the text): https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8b-P7UIzX09QTNSeGJ6OHhRdk0

and then when I close the windows I see

> invalid/unsupported opcode: 00 - 00 - 00 (00000000) 0x004f4000 1

What am I doing wrong?